# Derivative of Binary Cross Entropy - why are my signs not right?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, machine-learning

I'm trying to derive formulas used in backpropagation for a neural network that uses a binary cross entropy loss function.  When I perform the differentiation, however, my signs do not come out right:

Binary cross entropy loss function:
$$J(\hat y) = \frac{-1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m y_i\log(\hat y_i)+(1-y_i)(\log(1-\hat y)$$

where

$m = $ number of training examples 
$y = $ true y value 
$\hat y = $ predicted y value

When I attempt to differentiate this for one training example, I do the following process:

Product rule:
$$ \frac{dJ}{d\hat y_i} = -1(\frac{d}{d\hat y_i}(y_i\log(\hat y_i)+(1-y_i)(\log(1-\hat y)))) $$

Sum rule:
$$ = -1(\frac{d}{d\hat y_i}y_i\log(\hat y_i)+\frac{d}{d\hat y_i}(1-y_i)(\log(1-\hat y))) $$

Product rule, deriv of constant (treating $y$ as a constant) and deriv of natural log:
$$ = -1(\frac{y_i}{\hat y_i} + \frac{1-y_i}{1 - \hat y_i})$$

However, this is different from the expected result:
$$ \frac{dJ}{d\hat y_i} = -1(\frac{y_i}{\hat y_i} - \frac{1-y_i}{1 - \hat y_i}) $$

Not sure what's going wrong.  I'm sure I'm doing something incorrectly, but I can't figure out what it is.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\log(1-x)\neq \frac{1}{1-x}$. You need the chain rule, which will give you the required negative sign.

Comment: Thanks @AlexR.  I lost many hours to this.

Answer (score 28):

$$\mathbf{h} = \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{X} $$

$$\mbox{Logistic regression: }\mathbf{z} = \sigma(\mathbf{h}) = 
\frac{1}{1 + e^{-\mathbf{h}}}$$

$$\mbox{Cross-entropy loss: } J(\mathbf{w}) = 
-(\mathbf{y} log(\mathbf{z}) + (1 - \mathbf{y})log(1 - \mathbf{z})) $$
$$ \mbox{Use chain rule: } 
\frac{\partial{J(\mathbf{w})}}{\partial{\mathbf{w}}} = 
\frac{\partial{J(\mathbf{w})}}{\partial{\mathbf{z}}}
\frac{\partial{\mathbf{z}}}{\partial{\mathbf{h}}}
\frac{\partial{\mathbf{h}}}{\partial{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}}}$$

$$\frac{\partial{J(\mathbf{w})}}{\partial{\mathbf{z}}} = 
-(\frac{\mathbf{y}}{\mathbf{z}} - \frac{1-\mathbf{y}}{1-\mathbf{z}}) = 
\frac{\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y}}{\mathbf{z}(1-\mathbf{z})}$$

$$\frac{\partial{\mathbf{z}}}{\partial{\mathbf{h}}} = 
\mathbf{z}(1-\mathbf{z}) $$

$$\frac{\partial{\mathbf{h}}}{\partial{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}}} = 
\mathbf{X} $$

$$\frac{\partial{J(\mathbf{w})}}{\partial{\mathbf{w}}} = 
\mathbf{X}^T (\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{y})$$

$$\mbox{Gradient descent: } \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{w} - 
\alpha \frac{\partial{J(\mathbf{w})}}{\partial{\mathbf{w}}} $$

Comment: dJ/dw is derivative of sigmoid binary cross entropy with logits, binary cross entropy is dJ/dz where z can be something else rather than sigmoid

Comment: I just noticed that this derivation seems to apply for gradient descent of the last layer's weights only. I'm wondering how backpropagation to previous layer's weight matrices works. I've been studying the algorithm from chapter 2 of this book, which takes a very different approach:  http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html#the_backpropagation_algorithm

Comment: Is it possible to find a close form ? if yes, I cannot find it

Comment: @rocksNwaves you're right. The above derivation is for the last layer only which outputs a scalar. To compute gradient in the previous layer's weight matrices, you need to compute jacobian matrix since this is vector-vector transformation. Not vector-scalar like above.

Comment: @lalaland https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/949/when-is-logistic-regression-solved-in-closed-form check this post out

Comment: log of cross-entropy loss has base e? since derivative of ylog(z) w.r.t. z = y/zln(base)

Comment: What happens if $z = 0$ or $(1-z) = 0$?

Answer (score 6):

Let's denote the inner/Frobenius product by $a:b= a^Tb$ 

and the elementwise/Hadamard product by $a\odot b$

and elementwise/Hadamard division by $\frac{a}{b}$

and note that the $\log$ function is to be applied elementwise.

For convenience, let's use a modified loss function
$$L=-mJ$$
Then the differential and gradient of $L$ can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
L &= y:\log({\hat y}) + (1-y):\log(1-{\hat y}) \cr
\cr
dL &= y:d\log({\hat y}) + (1-y):d\log(1-{\hat y}) \cr
 &= \frac{y}{{\hat y}}:d{\hat y} + \frac{1-y}{1-{\hat y}}:d(1-{\hat y}) \cr
 &= \Big(\frac{y}{{\hat y}} - \frac{1-y}{1-{\hat y}}\Big):d{\hat y} \cr
 &= \Big(\frac{y-{\hat y}}{{\hat y}-{\hat y}\odot{\hat y}}\Big):d{\hat y} \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\hat y}}
 &= \frac{y-{\hat y}}{{\hat y}-{\hat y}\odot{\hat y}} \cr
\cr
}$$
And the gradient of the original cost function is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial J}{\partial{\hat y}}
 &= -\frac{1}{m}\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\hat y}}
 = \frac{{\hat y}-y}{m\,({\hat y}-{\hat y}\odot{\hat y})} \cr
}$$

Comment: that should be the trace of A.T*b, to indicate the frobenius product yes?

Comment: What happens if $\hat{y} \equiv 1$ and the denominator vanishes?

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider In that case, the $\large\log({\tt1}-\hat y)$ term in the cost function becomes undefined, and everything after that is likewise undefined.

Comment: Thanks, would you add any epsilon into the loss function to prevent that?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is almost correct except for the second term.  While taking derivative of  $(1-y_i)(\log(1-\hat y))$ w.r.t   $   \hat y$, 
 using product rule,
   $= (1-y_i)(\frac {1} {1-\hat y_i})* \frac {d(1-\hat y_i)}{d\hat y_i} $ 
  $ = (1-y_i)(\frac {1} {1-\hat y_i})*-1 $
 $ = - (\frac {1-y_i} {1-\hat y_i})$

Comment: IMO best explained!

Comment: But what if $\hat{y}_i = 1$